# Can one normalize a PCA for specific features?

Tags: pca, feature-selection

When dealing with data sets that have hundreds of dimensions, some phenotypic and some metadata, I would like to "normalize" the effect of specific (multiple) features on PCAs.

I can get the contribution of specific features by plotting biplots, however, I would like to present the data where the effect of these has been considered and normalized for.

I tried normalizing by specific columns, but not sure this is the right way to go about this, or whether or not I can do this for multiple ones. I'm more of a newbie to dimension reduction; I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Hi what coding you would like to do it in, e.g r, python, matlab .. ? And it would help if you show an example of what you have done, in that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running this in python, but r works too. I dont have a specific example to share, but will work on one and post here (probably later today or tomorrow).

Comment: I'm asking this because if it's a coding problem, for example, how to write the function for normalization etc, SO is the site. But if it is more of a statistical question, you might have to put it on cross validated.

Comment: So yeah, if you have an example, it will be great.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I guess it's more of a statistical question. I'll post it on Cross Validated.